# How to test model where variable moderates relationship via a mediating variable? (in lavaan)

Tags: interaction, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

Say you have variables X, Y, Z, and W.
I hypothesize that X impacts Y and this relationship is moderated by Z. Moreover, W impacts Z. Therefore, W moderates the relationship between X and Y via its impact on Z.

I am implementing this in lavaan with the following code:

```
model_definition <- '
Y ~ X + Z + X:Z
Z ~ W
'
fit <- sem(model_definition, data = df)
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE, rsq=TRUE)
```

Is this the correct implementation? Is there a way I can test if W moderates Y ~ X via Z? It's almost like a mediation model except the outcome is a moderating effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by translating the diagram on page 461 of Hayes 2015. It is the same as if you were conducting a mediation model where Z is a mediator, and the interaction term of X:W is like the "a" variable of a traditional mediation and X and W are like covariates.

```
model_definition <- '
Z ~ a1*X:W + a2*X + a3*W
Y ~ c1*X + c2*W + c3*X:W + b*Z
indirect := a3*b
total := c3 + indirect
'
fit <- sem(model_definition, data = df)
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE, rsq=TRUE)
```